# User Timing Data is not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to find the time difference between two events.(two button clicks)
After computing the time difference, the time in minutes is sent to GA using gtag method.

The event Resolution Time is showing up in Real Time. But the data is not showing up in User Timings tab in under Behaviour Tab.
why GA is not showing up the data sent?

```
function sendResolutionTime(time) {
            gtag('event', 'Resolution Time', {
                'name': 'Resolution Time',
                'value': time,
                'event_category': 'timingCategory',
                'event_label': 'timingLabel'
            });
```

Comment: Hey! "...the time in minutes is sent to GA using gtag method..." Don't forget that timingValue should be send in miliseconds (not in minutes). Check that.

Comment: And double check your gtag() syntax. Change second parameter from 'Resolution Time' to 'timing_complete' - here you have documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-timings

Comment: Thank you... How long does it takes for the data to show up in User Timings tab

Comment: Data should be visible in reports next day.

Answer (score -2):

```
attach(google.parent.ga)
if parent = *time*
then ping [*host*]
```

That should give you some results^